# Issue with canvas.find_overlapping()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My Program is fairly straightforward: user clicks and it makes a square, then if all the squares the user has made all squares touch or overlap they become red, if not they remain clear. My question is this: How am miss using the method or am I even using the right method for this program?

EDIT: The program does make the rectangles no problem: however I seem unable to use the canvas.find_overlapping to determine if all of the rectangles are connected. Am i missing something in this code?

```
from tkinter import * # Import tkinter
from Graph import Graph

def add(event):
    squares.append([event.x, event.y])
    repaint()

def repaint():
    canvas.delete(ALL)

    if len(squares) == 0: return # Nothing to paint
    tags = 0
    for [x, y] in squares:
        canvas.create_rectangle(x - side, y - side, x + side, y + side, tags = "point")
        tags += 1

    # Build the edges
    edges = []
    for i in range(len(squares)):
        x = canvas.find_overlapping(squares[i][0]-side, squares[i][1]-side, squares[i][0]+side , squares[i][1]+side)
        print(x)
        for j in range(i + 1, len(squares)):
            if squares[j] in x:
                edges.append([i, j])
                edges.append([j, i])

    graph = Graph(squares, edges)
    tree = graph.dfs(0)
    isAllSquaresConnected = \
        len(squares) == tree.getNumberOfVerticesFound()
    if isAllSquaresConnected:
        canvas.itemconfigure("point", fill = "red")





window = Tk() # Create a window
window.title("ConnectedSquares") # Set title

width = 250
height = 200
side = 15
canvas = Canvas(window, bg = "white", width = width, height = height)
canvas.pack()

# Create a 2-D list for storing squares
squares = []

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", add)

window.mainloop() # Create an event loop
```

this is the graph program mentioned as an import

```
from Queue import Queue 

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, vertices, edges):
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.neighbors = self.getAdjacnecyLists(edges)

    # Return a list of adjacency lists for edges 
    def getAdjacnecyLists(self, edges):
        neighbors = []
        for i in range(len(self.vertices)):
            neighbors.append([]) # Each element is another list

        for i in range(len(edges)):
            u = edges[i][0]
            v = edges[i][1]
            neighbors[u].append(v) # Insert a neighbor for u

        return neighbors

    # Return the number of vertices in the graph 
    def getSize(self):
        return len(self.vertices)

    # Return the vertices in the graph 
    def getVertices(self):
        return self.vertices

    # Return the vertex at the specified index
    def getVertex(self, index):
        return self.vertices[index]

    # Return the index for the specified vertex 
    def getIndex(self, v):
        return self.vertices.index(v)

    # Return the neighbors of vertex with the specified index 
    def getNeighbors(self, index):
        return self.neighbors[index]

    # Return the degree for a specified vertex 
    def getDegree(self, v):
        return len(self.neighbors[self.getIndex(v)])

    # Print the edges 
    def printEdges(self):
        for u in range(0, len(self.neighbors)):
            print(self.getVertex(u) + " (" + str(u), end = "): ")
            for j in range(len(self.neighbors[u])):
                print("(" + str(u) + ", " + 
                      str(self.neighbors[u][j]), end = ") ")
            print()

    # Clear graph 
    def clear(self):
        vertices = []
        neighbors = []

    # Add a vertex to the graph   
    def addVertex(self, vertex):
        if not (vertex in self.vertices):
            self.vertices.append(vertex)
            self.neighbors.append([]) # add a new empty adjacency list

    # Add an undirected edge to the graph   
    def addEdge(self, u, v):
        if u in self.vertices and v in self.vertices:
            indexU = self.getIndex(u)
            indexV = self.getIndex(v)
            if not (indexV in self.neighbors[indexU]):
                self.neighbors[indexU].append(indexV)

    # Obtain a DFS tree starting from vertex v 
    # To be discussed in Section 16.6 
    def dfs(self, v):
        searchOrders = []
        parent = len(self.vertices) * [-1] # Initialize parent[i] to -1

        # Mark visited vertices
        isVisited = len(self.vertices) * [False]

        # Recursively search
        self.dfsHelper(v, parent, searchOrders, isVisited)

        # Return a search tree
        return Tree(v, parent, searchOrders, self.vertices)

    # Recursive method for DFS search 
    def dfsHelper(self, v, parent, searchOrders, isVisited):
        # Store the visited vertex
        searchOrders.append(v)
        isVisited[v] = True # Vertex v visited

        for i in self.neighbors[v]:
            if not isVisited[i]:
                parent[i] = v # The parent of vertex i is v
                # Recursive search
                self.dfsHelper(i, parent, searchOrders, isVisited) 

    # Starting bfs search from vertex v 
    # To be discussed in Section 16.7 
    def bfs(self, v):
        searchOrders = []
        parent = len(self.vertices) * [-1] # Initialize parent[i] to -1

        queue = Queue() # the Queue class is defined in Chapter 12
        isVisited = len(self.vertices) * [False]
        queue.enqueue(v) # Enqueue v
        isVisited[v] = True # Mark it visited

        while not queue.isEmpty():
            u = queue.dequeue() # Dequeue to u
            searchOrders.append(u) # u searched
            for w in self.neighbors[u]:
                if not isVisited[w]:
                    queue.enqueue(w) # Enqueue w
                    parent[w] = u # The parent of w is u
                    isVisited[w] = True # Mark it visited

        return Tree(v, parent, searchOrders, self.vertices)

# Tree  class will be discussed in Section 16.5 
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root, parent, searchOrders, vertices):
        self.root = root # The root of the tree
        # Store the parent of each vertex in a list
        self.parent = parent 
        # Store the search order in a list
        self.searchOrders = searchOrders 
        self.vertices = vertices # vertices of the graph

    # Return the root of the tree 
    def getRoot(self):
      return self.root

    # Return the parent of vertex v 
    def getParent(self, index):
        return self.parent[index]

    # Return an array representing search order 
    def getSearchOrders(self):
        return self.searchOrders

    # Return number of vertices found 
    def getNumberOfVerticesFound(self):
        return len(self.searchOrders)

    # Return the path of vertices from a vertex index to the root 
    def getPath(self, index):
        path = []

        while index != -1:
            path.append(self.vertices[index])
            index = self.parent[index]

        return path

    # Print a path from the root to vertex v 
    def printPath(self, index):
        path = self.getPath(index)
        print("A path from " + str(self.vertices[self.root]) + " to " 
              + str(self.vertices[index]), end = ": ")
        for i in range(len(path) - 1, -1, -1):
            print(path[i], end = " ")

    # Print the whole tree 
    def printTree(self):
        print("Root is: " + str(self.vertices[self.root]))
        print("Edges: ", end = "")
        for i in range(len(self.parent)):
            if self.parent[i] != -1:
                # Display an edge
                print("(" + str(self.vertices[self.parent[i]]) 
                      + ", " + str(self.vertices[i]), end = ") ")

        print()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What's the problem? Does the code crash? Does it not draw rectangles? Is it not finding rectangles? Finding too many? Finding the wrong ones?

Comment: i will update it with a more clear issue

Comment: You wrote "I  seem unable to use the canvas.find_overlapping..." -- what does "unable" mean? Does it crash? Does it give an error? You haven't described the behavior you desire, and how it's different from the behavior you are getting.

Comment: the canvas.find_overlapping wasn't staying 1, 2, 3 ect. it would go (1, ) then (2, 3) (2, 3)....then (4, 5, 6)ect. the numbers it was returning kept changing and i wasn't able to use them. this is why i needed help. it wasn't even keeping the same numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change I had apparently needed was to determine the length of x and if the length of x == 1 then it wouldn't be all connected.

```
def repaint():
    canvas.delete(ALL)

    if len(squares) == 0: return # Nothing to paint
    tags = 0
    for [x, y] in squares:
        canvas.create_rectangle(x - side, y - side, x + side, y + side, tags = "point")
        tags += 1

    # Build the edges
    edges = []
    isAllSquaresConnected = True
    for i in range(len(squares)):
        x = canvas.find_overlapping(squares[i][0]-side, squares[i][1]-side, squares[i][0]+side , squares[i][1]+side)
        for j in range(i + 1, len(squares)):
            if len(x)  > 1:
                edges.append([i, j])
                edges.append([j, i])
            else:
                isAllSquaresConnected = False


    if isAllSquaresConnected:
        canvas.itemconfigure("point", fill = "red")
```